# Configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables when i used arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, xilinx

I am trying to cross compile my netperf-2.7.0 by downloading it and in the source directory of netperf-2.7.0 , configuring configure to compile for my arm cortex A9 using the following command

```
./configure CC=/opt/pkg/peta2017.1/Xilinx/SDK/2017.1/gnu/arm/lin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc --host arm --config-cache
```

But the following message is being displayed

```
configure: WARNING: if you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used
configure: creating cache config.cache
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-none
checking target system type... arm-unknown-none
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-gcc... /opt/pkg/peta2017.1/Xilinx/SDK/2017.1/gnu/arm/lin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/Downloads/netperf-2.7.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

Do i need to set any build environment for xilinx tool chain inorder to cross compile the downloaded source code for the netperf?
```

Comment: "`See config.log for more details`"

Comment: `./configure: line 3285: /opt/pkg/peta2017.1/Xilinx/SDK/2017.1/gnu/arm/lin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc: No such file or directory` it shows this message in config.log

Comment: Ahh.. i understood, it doesnot exist but when we want to cross compile we will export the path, set build environment and then cross compile but when i do in the regular manner, it shows this following message..  `export ARCH=arm
export PATH=/opt/pkg/peta2017.1/Xilinx/SDK/2017.1/gnu/arm/lin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/bin/
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi

source /opt/pkg/peta2017.1/Xilinx/SDK/2017.1/settings64.sh 

./configure CC=/opt/pkg/peta2017.1/Xilinx/SDK/2017.1/gnu/arm/lin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi -gcc --host arm --config-cache`  It is showing the following error

Comment: `./configure: line 434: sed: command not found
./configure: line 433: expr: command not found
./configure: line 434: sed: command not found
./configure: line 448: sed: command not found
: error: cannot create .lineno; rerun with a POSIX shell
`